# HTML JavaScript Stay on Div on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some working code below which is showing two divs based on two buttons that are clicked. Inside each div i have a refresh button.

When I click either of these buttons i want the page to reload (which it is currently doing) but i want it to load the save div that the button was clicked from. What do i need to change to make this work?

https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/qsbv50ff/3/

```
<center><img src='http://www.rdesignonline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/circle-plain.gif' usemap="#lsetmap" id="" alt="" /></center>
<map id="lsetMap" name="lsetmap">
  <area shape="circle" coords="96,77,40" href="#" alt="" item="div1" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="238,77,40" href="#" alt="" item="div2" />
</map>

<div id="div1" class="display">
  <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
    <tr>
      <td>### Some Table Data in Green Button ###</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input Type="button" VALUE="Reload Page" onClick="history.go(0)">
</div>

<div id="div2" class="display">
  <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
    <tr>
      <td>### Some Table Data in Red Button ###</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input Type="button" VALUE="Reload Page" onClick="history.go(0)">
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$(".display").hide();
$('[item]').click(function() {
  var item = $(this).attr('item');
  $(".display").hide();
  $("#" + item).show();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `Local/session storage` or `QueryString parameter`

Comment: Are you able to amend my code to show how I use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Set the state in `sessionStorage` using `sessionStorage.setItem` and get the state on page `load` using `sessionStorage.getItem`

```js
// Consider "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage'
// property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin'
// flag" while executing this snippet

$(".display").hide();
$('[item]').click(function() {
  var item = $(this).attr('item');
  sessionStorage.setItem('item', item);
  $(".display").hide();
  $("#" + item).show();
  return false;
});

var item = sessionStorage.getItem('item');
if (item) {
  $("#" + item).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <img src='http://www.rdesignonline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/circle-plain.gif' usemap="#lsetmap" id="" alt="" />
</center>
<map id="lsetMap" name="lsetmap">
  <area shape="circle" coords="96,77,40" href="#" alt="" item="div1" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="238,77,40" href="#" alt="" item="div2" />
</map>

<div id="div1" class="display">
  <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
    <tr>
      <td>### Some Table Data in Green Button ###</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input Type="button" VALUE="Reload Page" onClick="history.go(0)">
</div>

<div id="div2" class="display">
  <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
    <tr>
      <td>### Some Table Data in Red Button ###</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input Type="button" VALUE="Reload Page" onClick="history.go(0)">
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qsbv50ff/5/)

Comment: Nice, the only problem with this is on initial page load I want it to clear any selected divs. I.e. it should load nothing but the image on entry of page.

Comment: use just some variable or #hash in url when reloading the page to signalize which element to show after the page is reloaded.

Comment: If i use sessionStorage.clear(); the second time i hit the reload button it shows no divs again, how do i stop this? https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/qsbv50ff/6/

Comment: How exactly you want it to happen ? Initially, there will be nothing in `sessionStorage` hence `if` condition will not be satisfied..

Comment: So on initial page load I want no divs to load always. If I click on the refresh button inside each div I want the page to reload and show that div no matter how many times I click that refresh button.

Comment: And what is not happening in above example ?

Comment: So in this eample: https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/qsbv50ff/6/ On initial page load (run) no div is shown (which is correct) when i click the red circle and click refresh the page reloads with that div correctly shown. However when i click refresh again on the red square div on page reload it shows no divs again. I want it to continually show the div i clicked reload on.

Comment: This is because you are clearing it `sessionStorage.clear();`... Read about `sessionStorage`... It will be cleared when instance of the `browser` is closed..

Comment: Yes i see that, but i need it to not load a div on initial page load. So how do I achieve this then if i can't use sessionStorage.clear();

Comment: @Jaron787 when you load the page for the first time no div will be shown because sessionStorage is empty. After you click on the circles then only sessionstorage will be having some value and next time the page is loaded you will see the div. This happens to me as well when I tested

Comment: @SpringLearner what happens when you click the reload page button twice? On the second click the div is lost which is incorrect. I added sessionStorage.clear(); because on initial page load i dont want any divs to be displayed. If i dont use sessionStorage.clear(); on initial page load (for the second time) it will keep the last div opened which is incorrect.

Comment: @Jaron787 I clicked reload button 10 times, div is not lost.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/qsbv50ff/9/ - Please look at this example. On second reload button click div is lost...

Comment: I have posted a new question - HTML Java Script - Stay on div on page refresh button click